# Conditional Printing with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, printing, conditional-statements

Once again, apologies if this is a dumb question... my current situation is that I'm having to do some work in XSLT and I really don't know a lot about it. I'm learning, but I still need help understanding things.

Before I ask my question, given this XML:

```
<group>
    <person>
        <datum type='sex'>f</datum>
        <datum type='name'>Gina</datum>
        <datum type='age'>40</datum>
    </person>
    <person>
        <datum type='sex'>m</datum>
        <datum type='name'>Fred</datum>
        <datum type='age'>50</datum>
    </person>
    <person>
        <datum type='sex'>m</datum>
        <datum type='name'>Charles</datum>
        <datum type='age'>30</datum>
    </person>
    <person>
        <datum type='sex'>f</datum>
        <datum type='name'>Betty</datum>
        <datum type='age'>20</datum>
    </person>
    <person>
        <datum type='sex'>?</datum>
        <datum type='name'>Pat</datum>
        <datum type='age'>15</datum>
    </person>
    <person>
        <datum type='sex'>?</datum>
        <datum type='name'>Jamie</datum>
        <datum type='age'>55</datum>
    </person>
</group>
```

And this XSLT:

[image: Transformation]

Which yields this result:

[image: Simple output]

And, now, finally, my question. How do I modify the XSLT to yield a result something like this:

[image: formatted output]

I assume I want to track when each person's sex changes and insert a new row when it occurs, and, therefore, do something like this in the XSLT:

```
<xsl:if test="datum[@type='sex'] != $last">
```

But that's my problem. I know variables in XSLT are not modifiable, so... what is the best way to accomplish this task? I've searched all over the All-Knowing 'Net for the answer, but haven't found any good examples on how to do this.

As always, any and all clues appreciated.

Comment: You can use grouping. If you are using XSLT 2.0 look at examples of `for-each-group`. In XSLT 1.0 search for [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a XSLT 1.0 stylesheet which produces the result you expect using [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="sex" match="person" use="datum[@type='sex']"/>

    <xsl:template match="person">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="datum[@type='name']"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="datum[@type='age']"/></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="group">
        <table border="1">
        <xsl:for-each select="person[count(. | key('sex', datum[@type='sex'])[1]) = 1]/datum[@type='sex']">
            <tr><td colspan="2"><xsl:value-of select="."/></td></tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//person[datum[@type='sex'] = current()]"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You have to look for non-sequential solutions when using XSLT. You can solve many problems recursively and not need to change the values of any variables.

You can see the code it generates in this **[XSLT Fiddle](http://xsltransform.net/pPgCcoE)**

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, your comment about non-sequential solutions is precisely why I pointed out that I've never used XSLT before. I'm, at present, trying to understand how to use the technology, but most of the tutorials I find out there don't really give me a good handle on how it needs to be approached. This definitely helps.

Comment: OK, followup question: In my original example, I included a sort. When I try adding it back, after the the for-each, I cannot get it to sort. What am I missing here? I assume it's an XPath issue, I'm just not clear yet what it might be.

Comment: You can include the `<xs:sort>` inside the `<xsl:apply-templates><xsl:sort ...></xsl:apply-templates>` to sort the contents of each group. The *sort* in the for-each would sort the groups.

Comment: Got it figured out. I tried everything but this: <xsl:sort select="." /> . I'm assuming <xsl:sort> means the same as what I inserted.

Comment: OK, another follow up question, if I may. Given the value we are sorting on is blank/empty, how do I sort on that empty value as if it had a value anyway? So, forget that sex is defined as '?' but rather has no value, how do I get it to sort as if it were '?' ?

Comment: You would have to use some other criterion, since sort can sort strings or numbers. Empty strings will be sorted by their position as an empty string. AFAIK you can only do that in XSLT 2.0 or + where you can define collations and perform conditional sorts based on XPath expressions.